# Show busy image during writing to sheet

Tags: office-js

I'm working on an Excel add-in using the JavaScript APIs to build add-ins in Excel Office 365.
I want to show a busy image for the time during which Excel is writing data to the sheet from the JSON it received from the server. Is there a way to achieve this ?

Note : - Since the JSON received has around 50 K records, there is a bit of lag and user can see nothing in the excel during the time it is  writing the received data to the Excel. A busy image would help during the lag.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the asynchronous nature of OfficeJs, it doesn't lock the UI. It uses the idle time between UI operations and does its work. One of the effects is that you can't block the UI. In some scenarios it may be easy to block users from doing any UI interaction and it is one of our design questions under discussion. No API to help with this scenario yet...

Comment: Is there still no way to prevent the user doing things in the UI while an add-in is actively working on things (that may need `context.sync()` periodically, so have to yield)?

Comment: No, it is not possible to take control of the UI thread. All APIs are async in nature and gives the control back to main process.

Comment: Thanks! But I don't want to control the UI thread. :-) I want to do what seems like a really basic thing: Prevent the user from doing something while my add-in is doing something, since in the normal course of things, while the add-in is doing X the user can do things like switch worksheets, right in the middle of something the add-in is doing. I can do a spinning indicator on the add-in, but that doesn't stop users doing silly things. In the old VBA days there was a way to lock updates from the user and then unlock them. Is there really no such thing??